# load test gui with jmeter and selenium webdriver

Tags: java, testing, selenium-webdriver, jmeter

I created a java wrapper to feed jmeter. I have implemented java classes with selenium that are invoked by the wrapper and perform GUI tests.
I activated the headless option.
launching tests with a single user from jmeter all works correctly.
trying to launch two users tests fail.
can you help me to understand why?

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you missed an important bit: each Selenium session need to have a separate URL and Selenium server needs to be running on a different port. So make sure to amend your "wrapper" to be aware of multiple WebDriver instances and to kick off a separate instance of Selenium server (or standalone client) for each JMeter thread (virtual user).

Unfortunately we cannot help further without seeing your code, just keep in mind that your wrapper needs to be [thread-safe](https://www.journaldev.com/1061/thread-safety-in-java). Also pay attention to *jmeter.log* file - normally it should contain enough information to get to the bottom of your test failure.

---

P.S. Are you aware of [WebDriver Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler) plugin? It's designed in line with JMeter threads model and you should be able to kick off as many browsers as your machine can handle. If you for some reason it doesn't fit your needs you can at least take a look into the [source code](https://github.com/undera/jmeter-plugins/tree/master/plugins/webdriver) to get an idea with regards to what you need to change in your "wrapper"